# How to drill down data using pandas - pythonic way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(100)
cdf = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'grade': rng.choice(list('ACD'),size=(5)),
                   'dash': rng.choice(list('PQRS'),size=(5)),
                   'dumeel': rng.choice(list('QWER'),size=(5)),
                   'dumma': rng.choice((1234),size=(5)),
                   'target': rng.choice([0,1],size=(5))
})
```

My objective is to compute the drill down info for each column

Let me explain by an example.

If we filter the dataframe by `df[df['grade']=='A']`, we get 2 records as result. let's consider the filtered column `grade` as parent_variable. Out of those 2 records returned as result, how much `dumeel` column (`child_variable`) values and `dash` column (`child_variable`) values account for `target` column values (which is 0 and 1). All categorical/object columns other than parent variable are called child variables.

We have to repeat the above exaple procedure for all the categorical/object variables in our dataset

As a first step, I made use of the below from a SO post

```
funcs = {
  'cnt of records': 'count',
  'target met': lambda x: sum(x),
  'target met %': lambda x: f"{round(100 * sum(x) / len(x), 2):.2f}%"
}

out = df.select_dtypes('object').melt(ignore_index=False).join(df['target']) \
        .groupby(['variable', 'value'])['target'].agg(**funcs).reset_index()
out.rename(columns={'variable': 'parent_variable','value': 'parent_value'}, inplace=True)
```

But the above, gets me only the `%` and `count` of `target` based on all parent variable. I would like to get the breakdown by child variables as well (for each parent variable)

`%_contrib` is obtained by computing the % of that record to the target value. ex: for `dash=P`, we have one grade values `A` (for target = 1). So, it has to be 100%. Hope this helps.

I expect my output to be like as shown below. I have shown sample only for couple of columns under parent_variable. But in my real data, there will be more than 20 categorical variables. So, any efficient approach is welcome and useful

[image]

Comment: Can you "freeze" your DataFrame? I mean - as you are using a random function to generate it - we will all get different Dataframes and your explanation becomes harder to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a random function to generate the `DataFrame` it is hard for me to reproduce your example, but I think you are looking for `value_counts` -

This is the `DataFrame` I generated with your code -

```
  grade dash dumeel  dumma  target
0     D    P      W     50       1
1     D    S      R    595       0
2     C    P      E    495       1
3     A    Q      Q    690       0
4     B    P      W    653       1
5     D    R      E    554       0
6     C    P      Q    392       1
7     D    Q      Q    186       0
8     B    Q      E   1228       1
9     C    P      E     14       0
```

When I do a `value_counts()` on the two columns -

```
df[(df['dash']=='P') & (df['target'] == 1)]['dumeel'].value_counts(normalize=True)
W    0.50
Q    0.25
E    0.25
Name: dumeel, dtype: float64

df[(df['dash']=='P') & (df['target'] == 1)]['grade'].value_counts(normalize=True)
C    0.50
D    0.25
B    0.25
Name: grade, dtype: float64
```

If you want to loop over all the `child_columns` - you can do

```
excl_cols = ['dash', 'target']
child_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in excl_cols]
for col in child_cols:
    print(df[(df['dash']=='P') & (df['target'] == 1)][col].value_counts(normalize=True))
```

If you want to loop over all the columns - then you can use:

```
loop_columns = set(df.columns) - {'target'}
for parent_col in loop_columns:
    print(f'Parent column is {parent_col}\n')
    parent_vals = df[parent_col].unique()
    child_cols = loop_columns - {parent_col}
    for parent_val in parent_vals:
        for child_col in child_cols:
            print(df[(df[parent_col]==parent_val) & (df['target'] == 1)][child_col].value_counts(normalize=True))
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. but I may not be able to provide column names manually as my real dataframe has more than 100 columns.

Comment: In that case you can loop over the said `child_columns` - see edited answer.

Comment: There is no exclusive column such as `grade`. Meaning, the `parent variable` is also supposed to change.

Comment: Meaning, each variable will be a parent variable once. except the nnumeric columns

Comment: Edited the answer to use each column as a parent column once and the rest of the columns as child_columns iteratively